# how to align heading in center and icon in right on the same line and is responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How to align heading in center of the line and icon in right side of the same line (it should be responsive).

```
<h6 class="card-title ">Activity</h6> 
<a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
   <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Can you provide a paint drawing or a picture of how do you want to align the items? Your description is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with either grid or flexbox, I suggest you use grid, since it's easier to control the width of the title and the icon. Check the snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row border border-primary">
    <h1 class="col-10 text-center border border-secondary">My Title</h1>
    <span class="col-2 d-flex align-items-center">My Icon</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="option1">
<h6 class="card-title ">Activity <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
   <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
</a></h6> 
</div>

<div class="option2">
<div style="float:left">
<h6 class="card-title" style="margin-top:0">Activity</h6> 
</div>
<div style="float:right">
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">
   <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
</a>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I think we might need a bit more info but this should get you started.